# If A/k and B/k are normal, show that (A \cap B)/k is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Question: Suppose that $K/k$ is a field extension, and $K$ is algebraically closed.
Let $k \subseteq A  \subseteq K$ and $k \subseteq B  \subseteq K$ with $A/k$ and $B/k$ normal extensions.
Show that $A \cap B/k$ is a normal extension.

Attempt: 
Let $f\in k[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial that has a root, say $\alpha$, in $A \cap B$. To show normality, we must show that $f$ splits over $A \cap B$.
Clearly $\alpha \in A$ so by normality $f$ must split over $A$. Similarly with $B$.
Then all of $f$'s  roots are in both $A$ and $B$ and so they are all in $A \cap B$ as well. Hence $f$ splits over $A \cap B$ as required.

My attempt seems too simplistic to be right, and I haven't used $K$ at all, which makes me think I'm missing something. If I've gone wrong somewhere I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: You have used $K$ to define $A\cap B$, and to make sense of "all of $f$'s roots are in both $A$ and $B$". With that in mind, your proof is correct

Comment: @Max could you explain that further? I'm not sure why the proof wouldn't work without K, couldn't we just have field extensions A and B without K?

Comment: How do you define $A\cap B$ if you just have extensions $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: @Max I would think it would just be the intersection of the two fields? If we had k \subset A and  k \subset B, then we would have a field extension A \cap B/k wouldn't we?
I think I'm missing something.

Comment: The problem is that this is a set theoretic intersectuon. In particular, $f$ can have all its roots in $A$, all its roots in $B$, but no roots on $A\cap B$ if $A, B$ "misbehave set-theoretically". Here's an example : take $f=X^2-2$, over $k=\mathbb Q$. Then take on the one hand $A=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) \subset \mathbb R$ and $B= \mathbb Q[X]/(X^2-2)$ (where we removed the constant polynomials and replaced them by actual elements of $\mathbb Q$). Then both of these contain two roots of $f$, so all the roots, but their set-theoretic intersection is uninteresting : it's $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The point is that that's not what we want : the set-theoretic intersection is basically useless for abstract extensions that live in completely different worlds. What we want is an intersection that makes sense, and for an intersection to make sense in an algebraic context we have to have some bigger thing (here : field) where our objects live

Comment: @Max thanks, I think I understand now.

Comment: The idea is that the "correct" definition of a field extension is not with $k\subset A$, but it's a field embedding $k\to A$.Then it becomes clear that asking what $A\cap B$ is makes no sense without a larger field (it could be empty !)